# Export any project to Figma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, figma

Is there a way to create a Figma file from any content we want?

For example, I have the following React components:

[image]

As you can see the yellow cards I want to export them somehow to Figma, where the user can copy them and import them to Figma with the same content, how can I do this using react.js? or any special technology for Figma? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there are no such plugins.
The only option is to manually create the first version of the card, and then use it as a basis and just copy and change the text.